# Some questions about Lebesgue measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Recently, I have some trouble with Lebesgue Measurable Set.

My teacher said the inverse proposition of the following theorem is also valid.

> $Propositon: Suppose\ that\ E\ is \ a \ Lebesgue\ measurable \ set,\
> then\ \forall \epsilon>0, \exists \ open \ set\ G,\ s.t.\ E\subset G\
> and\ m(G-E)<\epsilon.$

> $Inverse\ Proposition: Suppose\ that\ E\subset
> \mathbb{R}^n,\ if\ \forall \epsilon>0, \exists \ open \ set\ G,\ s.t.\ E\subset G\ and\ m^*(G-E)<\epsilon, then\ E\ is\ Lebesgue\ measurable.$

I tried to prove the inverse proposition, and what I thought as follows.

$Proof: \forall \frac{1}{n},n\in \mathbb{N},\exists \ open \ set\ G_n,\ s.t.\ E\subset G_n\ and\ m^*(G_n-E)<\frac{1}{n}\\
Let\ O=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n, then\ O\ is\ G_{\delta}\ set,\ which\ is \ also\ measurable.\ Besides,\ we\ still\ have\ E\subset O.\\
From\ the\ monotonicity\ of\ Lebesgue\ Outer\ Measure,\ we\ have\\
m^*(O-E)\leq m^*(G_n-E)\leq \frac{1}{n},\forall n\in \mathbb{N}\Rightarrow\ m^*(O-E)=0.\\
O-E\ is\ also\ measurable,\ then\ we\ have\ E=O-(O-E)\ is\ also\ measurable.$

However, I notice that we don't know whether $G_{\delta}$ is an open set. In this way, we can't illustrate the existance of open set.How can I fix this? Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: But a $G_{\delta}$ is Borel and that is enough, because each Lebesgue measurable set is a union of a null and a Borel.

Comment: In general this intersection of open sets will not be open. But there is no need for any conclusion that it is open.

Comment: I seem to see what you mean. Just prove that it's measurable. It doesn't matter whether it is in the open set. Thank you.